# How to Change Default Position of Listview Item display on top of AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to change the default position of listView items as it is starting below AppBar But I want it to start with AppBar. Here is the code for ListView That I am using and code for appBar. How do I make my ListView starts from behind the appBar as using listview Normaly it's staring below the appBar

```
Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,64),
        child: Container(
          child: ClipRect(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3,sigmaY: 3),
              child: Material(
                elevation: 50.0,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                shadowColor: Colors.black,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 88,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child:  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 15),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Icon(Icons.line_weight),
                          const SizedBox(width: 15,),
                          Image.asset("assets/images/icon.png",height: 27.36,width: 41.84,),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          const Text("Travel Eyes Pvt Ltd", style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontFamily: "Inter",fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                              color: Color(0xFF000000),
                              shadows: [
                                Shadow(
                                    offset: Offset(0,4),
                                    blurRadius: 11
                                )
                              ]
                          ),),
                          SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 340,),
                          Container(
                            width: 111.6,
                            height: 27.6,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xFFE53900),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: const Color(0xFF000000)
                                ),
                                boxShadow: const[
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    offset: Offset(0, 4),
                                    blurRadius: 4,
                                  )
                                ]
                            ),
                            child: const Center(child: Text("Enquire Now",style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                                fontFamily: "Inter", fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontSize: 12),)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
ListView(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage(
          'assets/images/backgroundHome.png',
        ),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        colorFilter:
            ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black45, BlendMode.difference),
      )),
      child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: RichText(
            text: const TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Inter",
                    fontSize: 40,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                children: [
                  WidgetSpan(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                    child: Text("Where Dreams Take Flight:",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Inter",
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 50,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  )),
                  WidgetSpan(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                    child: Text("Explore the globe with Travel Eyes",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Inter",
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 50,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ))
                ]),
          )),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.orange,
      height: 100,
    )
  ],
),
);
```

- The Result I am getting

[image: The Result I am getting]

- The Result I want

[image: The Result I want]

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your ListView with Scaffold, and then put this property,

**extendBodyBehindAppBar: true**

```
Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    body: ListView(..)
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have added that but it's taking effect after scrolling

Comment: what effect do you mean on scrolling? @Ritikverma

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `ListView` inside a Column and place the `AppBar` widget above the `ListView.`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            AppBar(
              title: Text('Your Title'),
              elevation:0,
             
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.GPgOs_sd9nF8fsKDOJe9dQHaEo?w=278&h=180&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7',
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                          Colors.black45,
                          BlendMode.difference,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: RichText(
                        text: const TextSpan(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Inter",
                            fontSize: 40,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          children: [
                            WidgetSpan(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Where Dreams Take Flight:",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 50,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            WidgetSpan(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Explore the globe with Travel Eyes",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 50,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It won't work as app bar will come before my list view item But what I want is that image come on behind appBar at default

Comment: The result I want is second image

Comment: If not then this code should work  `Scaffold(extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,body: ListView(..))`.

Comment: I have done that but items goes behind the appBar after scrolling

Answer (score 0):

**In Scafold you can put it the code!**

```
extendBodyBehindAppBar: true
```

Then change the appbar background color to transparent

Comment: That also I have done

Comment: I have uploaded full code starting from Scaffold

Comment: so then. y'r problem solved!

Comment: No my problem is that ListView item are being displayed below appBar by default but I want it to show below appBar by default